# Upgrading from 5.2.2 to 6.4.2 (yum install VS yum update)

Tags: elasticsearch

Need to perform upgrade on 3-nodes ES clusters and writing test script before putting it to playbook. Anyone updated ES with yum update instead of install (OS AWS RHEL 7.2) ???

Here's the install script, I will be grateful for your comments:

```
#Installing from the RPM repository
#Create a file called elasticsearch.repo in the /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory for RedHat based distributions, 

#DO UPGRADE
#In the terms of ordering, update first the master nodes, then data nodes, then load-balancing/client nodes.

#Disable Shard reallocation
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient" : { "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "none" } }'

#Shutdown the instance:
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes/_local/_shutdown'

sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch
sudo yum update elasticsearch
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch

#Enable shard re-allocation:
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient" : { "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "all" } }'

#Watch cluster go from yellow state to green with:
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v // monitors the overal cluster state
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v // verify that the new node joined the cluster
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v // see shards being started, initialized and relocated

#Repeat for the next node.
```

Kind Regards,
P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. YUM UPDATE will upgrade the ES the the LATEST version.

Make sure you have:

1) updated the /etc/yum.repos.d/elasticsearch.repo to the latest 6.x version

2) all indexes have been created with version lateter than 5.x (if not they have to be reindexed)

```
curl -X GET http://host_ip:9200/index_name/_settings?pretty\&human
```

Kind Regards,
P.